# Porting from Linux-> Windows using Code::Blocks IDE tool

Tags: linux, windows, porting

I have one application(stress tool) which need to be ported Linux->Windows, someone suggested me to use "Code::Blocks" IDE, how does it helpfull and how it going to handle POSIX calls and system realted API's

Comment: What does Google say?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to handle the POSIX calls on windows. Code::Blocks can be configured to be used with the Cygwin toolchain.